# Btrfs copy snapshot with rsync

Tags: rsync, btrfs, snapshot

So I have been searching for this up and down, but must be doing something fundamentally wrong. What I want to do:

I have configured my NAS to make snapshots of my home folder, file system is btrfs. That works as it should and is utilizing hard links.

I want to copy off the whole snapshots directory for backup on an ext4 usb disk, using rsync -aH to preserve the hard links. But hard links are not preserved after rsync completes - I am down to a minimum example where I rsync a file of 2 different snapshots (verified to have identical Inodes) on the btrfs volume - just to another directory - which also creates 2 distinct files. Am I missing an rsync option here to make this work? Or is rsync simply incapable to do this? Wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know `rsync` very well but if by "snapshots" you mean Btrfs snapshots (taken with `btrfs subvolume snapshot …`) then identical files in two snapshots are not hardlinked.

They possibly share space on the (physical) device because of the copy-on-write behavior of Btrfs; their inode numbers are the same, but they logically exist on different devices. In this context each Btrfs subvolume should be treated as a separate filesystem.

If you can, check files belonging to different snapshots with `stat`. You will see they report different device identifiers. Identical inode numbers on different devices mean nothing.

For this reason `rsync` has no simple clue the files "should" be hardlinked. They are *not* hardlinked in your "whole snapshots directory" in the first place.

I believe `btrfs send` and `btrfs receive` are tools to replicate snapshot hierarchy on another computer (with Btrfs filesystem). I have never used them though, so I cannot guide you. Study `man btrfs-send` and `man btrfs-receive`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamil, I was blinded by the inodes having identical values. I'll give the tools you mentioned a shot.